# Empty alt tags wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, alt

I'm using WordPress with Listingpro template, I've been looking around for a solution and I've found the following:

```
// An attachment/image ID is all that's needed to retrieve its alt and title attributes.
$image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();    
$image_alt = get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);  
$image_title = get_the_title($image_id);
```

But, when I add this `alt='$image_alt'` showed me an empty alt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="whatever-src" alt="'.$image_alt.'">
```

This is what you need, when it is inside echo.
Only if there is any alt associated with that image.